Does Dune: Imperium mobile (Android) support cross-platform play?
I'm planning to play Dune: Imperium with some friends (they're on PC); however, I'm not sure if the mobile version supports cross-platform game sessions.
I checked the Play Store app description, and it didn't seem to mention anything about cross-platform functionality.
Can anyone with the Dune: Imperium Android version confirm this? The game isn't that cheap where I live, so I just wanted to check first before committing to the game.

According to a release page from Direwolf Digital,

The highly-acclaimed board game adaptation Dune: Imperium Digital will release cross-platform on March 13 on Steam, Xbox, Android, and iOS!

